# Could not find type DbCommandDefinition in System.Data.Common and in System.Data.Entity.Core.Common

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, webapi

Can someone  help me with this error:

> [InvalidOperationException: Could not find type DbCommandDefinition in System.Data.Common and in System.Data.Entity.Core.Common]
>
> HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.EntityFramework.EntityFrameworkProfiler.SetupDatabaseDefaultConnectionFactoryIfNeeded()
> +913    HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.EntityFramework.EntityFrameworkProfiler.SetupEntityFrameworkIntegration()
> +19    HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.EntityFramework.EntityFrameworkProfiler.Initialize()
> +37    FruconService.App_Start.EntityFrameworkProfilerBootstrapper.PreStart()
> +23
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
> System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo
> method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig,
> MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) +0
> System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method,
> Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes
> methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) +72
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
> invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture,
> Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) +335
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
> invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> +28    System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +19
> WebActivator.BaseActivationMethodAttribute.InvokeMethod() +221
> WebActivator.ActivationManager.RunActivationMethods() +491
> WebActivator.ActivationManager.RunPreStartMethods() +28
> WebActivator.ActivationManager.Run() +55
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivator.ActivationManager threw an exception
> with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the
> target of an invocation..]
> System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1
> methods) +423
> System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() +306
> System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
> appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
> configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
> PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +677
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivator.ActivationManager threw an exception
> with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the
> target of an invocation..]
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9088796
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
> +258"

It appears on my MVC4 Web API that is deployed on our web server.  We noticed that the error temporary goes away after re-deploy the binaries.  Then, the error comes back after some hours.

setup:

WC4 wep API
EF5 + EF5.x DB context generator for VB.Net

EDIT: I noticed a reference to `HibernateRhinos` in the stack trace.  This is a part of a 3th party EF-profiler that I tried.
For now, I removed this profiler from the project to see if the error comes up again or not.  To be honest, I suspect this component....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I answer this topic myself.
The problem was surely related to the 3th-party component.   I didn't have the problem since i removed it.

I post this because it can help other people...